# here map error message unknown in android application pops

Tags: android, here-api

Why UNKNOW error message is thrown during here map I followed all the steps
provided in the documentation. Registered in the developer console and I am using the correct appId, appCode, appApiKey

```
   @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                Window window = getWindow();
                window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
                window.setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.clr_black));
            }
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.my_location);
            getSupportActionBar().setDefaultDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0);
            // Search for the map fragment to finish setup by calling init().
            mapFragment = (MapFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapfragment);
            mapFragment.init(new OnEngineInitListener() {
                @Override
                public void onEngineInitializationCompleted(OnEngineInitListener.Error error) {
                    if (error == OnEngineInitListener.Error.NONE) {
                        // retrieve a reference of the map from the map fragment
                        map = mapFragment.getMap();
                        // Set the map center to the Vancouver region (no animation)
                        map.setCenter(new GeoCoordinate(49.196261, -123.004773, 0.0),
                                Map.Animation.NONE);
                        // Set the zoom level to the average between min and max
                        map.setZoomLevel(
                                (map.getMaxZoomLevel() + map.getMinZoomLevel()) / 2);
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("ERROR: Cannot initialize Map Fragment " + error.toString());
                        Toast.makeText(MyLocation.this, " Error: " + error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            });
        }

any suggestions.
```

Answer (score 1):

Which is the android version on your device ? Currently the SDK does not support Android 6.0 a work around to mae it work on 6.0 is mentioned in documentation. 
https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android-hybrid-plus/topics/app-simple-android-studio.html
"Note: The HERE SDK does not currently support Android Target API Level 23. Certain functionalities may fail if your application is set to API target 23. Please ensure targetSdkVersion is set to Level 22 or below. Level 23 will be supported in a future release."

Comment: Is this still the case? If so what version of the SDK allowed for 6.0? The release notes claim 3.0.1 allowed for Android M support, but 3.1.1's API changes claim  they [```Added support for Android Target API Level 23.```](https://developer.here.com/documentation/download/maps_android_nlp_hybrid_plus/3.1.1/HERE%20Android%20SDK%20Premium%20Edition%20v3.1.1%20Release%20Notes.pdf)

Comment: That is correct, from version 3.1.1 API 23 is supported but permissions have to added on run-time as well . https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android-hybrid-plus/topics/app-simple-android-studio.html

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem. I'm using the BasicMapSolution from the SDK bundle as template for my demo application. On the device to which I'm deploying the app is Android 4.0.3 running. TargetSdkVersion in the gradle file is set to 17 and compiledSdkVersion is set to 21.

To solve the problem I renamed the folder with the native libraries from src/main/jniLibs/armeabi to src/main/jniLibs/**armeabi-v7a**.
I think that's wrong in the tutorial!

Now the "UNKNOWN" error doesn't occure anymore, I can access the map and initialize it. But the map is never rendered. I think that is a new problem (device specific) :-/